# Understanding latex custom command change item indentation size

Tags: latex, indentation

I am trying to work on a latex template.
It has a user command that indents job duties under job description

```
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}
```

[image: here is how the indentation appears]

The indentation is too far from the left and I wish to move the indentation a bit to the left.

I have tired:

```
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt} \hspace{-5pt}}
```

with no effect on the document.

How can I modify this command to make indentation a little smaller?

What does `\item #1` mean in the custom command?

Edit:  [reproducible sample here](https://gist.github.com/rishirdua/81c3ff3de192c5c591f6)

Comment: Please make a [mre]. How to change the `leftmargini` and `leftmarginii` will depend on your class and packages.

Comment: the starting code can be found herehttps://gist.github.com/rishirdua/81c3ff3de192c5c591f6

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `enumitem` package. This means you can either adjust the margins locally, e.g.

```
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=10pt]
```

or globally for the whole document with

```
\setlist{leftmargin=10pt}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist{leftmargin=10pt}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,%
    citecolor=black,%
    filecolor=black,%
    linkcolor=black,%
    urlcolor=black
    %urlcolor=mygreylink     % can put red here to better visualize the links
}
\urlstyle{same}
\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{.87}
\definecolor{mygreylink}{gray}{.30}
\textheight=9.0in
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.375in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{0.375in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{0.5in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.375in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{0.75in}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Custom commands
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{{\fontsize{1.2em}{1em} \colorbox{mygrey}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}{\textbf{\textcolor{black}{#1
 \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}}\end{minipage}}}}


\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{
\begin{tabular*}{6.9in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        {#3} & {#4} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-6.8pt}}

\newcommand{\reprojheading}[3]{
\begin{tabular*}{6.58in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} #2& #3 \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}}



\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\fontfamily{\sfdefault}
\selectfont


{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}
\begin{tabular}{ p{0.70\linewidth} p{0.30\linewidth} }
 \multirow{3}{*}{ \fontfamily{\sfdefault} \selectfont \Huge XYZ}
&  \small \hfill {abc@def.com}\\
& \small \hfill  {xyz}\\
& \small \hfill {xyz}\\
\end{tabular}
}

\vspace{-0.66em}%\resheading{Education}
\begin{itemize}[parsep=0.8pt, leftmargin=0.3em]
        \item []
            \ressubheading{University}{Grad date}
            {Course, Dept}{xyz}
                { 
                }
\end{itemize}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\resheading{Work Experience}
    \begin{itemize}[parsep=0.8pt]
        \item 
            \reprojheading{Intern}{}{May 2014 -- Jul 2014}
                { 
                \begin{itemize}
                    \resitem{did abc}
                    \resitem{did abc}
                    \resitem{did abc}
                \end{itemize}
                }
        \item 
            \reprojheading{Intern}{}{May 2014 -- Jul 2014}
                { 
                \begin{itemize}
                    \resitem{did abc}
                    \resitem{did abc}
                    \resitem{did abc}
                \end{itemize}
                }
        \item 
            \reprojheading{Intern}{}{May 2014 -- Jul 2014}
                { 
                \begin{itemize}
                    \resitem{did abc}
                    \resitem{did abc}
                    \resitem{did abc}
                \end{itemize}
                }
    \end{itemize}

\resheading{Projects}
    \begin{itemize}[parsep=0.8pt]
        \item 
            \reprojheading{Intern}{}{May 2014 -- Jul 2014}
                { 
                \begin{itemize}
                    \resitem{did abc}
                    \resitem{did abc}
                    \resitem{did abc}
                \end{itemize}
                }
                \item 
            \reprojheading{Intern}{}{May 2014 -- Jul 2014}
                { 
                \begin{itemize}
                    \resitem{did abc}
                    \resitem{did abc}
                    \resitem{did abc}
                \end{itemize}
                }
                \item 
            \reprojheading{Intern}{}{May 2014 -- Jul 2014}
                { 
                \begin{itemize}
                    \resitem{did abc}
                    \resitem{did abc}
                    \resitem{did abc}
                \end{itemize}
                }

            %   }
    \end{itemize}  % End Projects and Experience list

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\resheading{Programming Experience}
\begin {itemize}[parsep=0.8pt, itemsep=1pt]
    \item Exp1
    \item Exp1
    \item Exp1
    \item Exp1
\end{itemize}


\resheading{Scholastic Achievements and Awards}
    \begin {itemize}[parsep=0.8pt, itemsep=1pt]
    \item Exp1
    \item Exp1

    \item Exp1
    \item Exp1
    \item Exp1
    \item Exp1
    \item Exp1
    \item Exp1

    \end{itemize} 
    

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much your answer works! one question though, do you happen to know what does \item #1  do?

Comment: @NullNull `#1` stands for the first argument of the macro, so it expands to `\item did abc`